# counting rows in csv file before bulk insert , non empty file check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I have a csv file and am trying to run bulk insert. But before I do bulk insert I want to make sure this file is not having only the column header row. It should have at least 1 row of data.

```
 select count(*) from openrowset(BULK 'file.csv', SINGLE_NCLOB) output
```

Above sql statement returns everything as 1 row. But I want the total row count in that csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You are super close to it, you just do not need to select count, because that is simply telling you that you are trying to load from 1 file.

Instead you can do the following:

```
DECLARE @lengthOfFile INT
SELECT @lengthOfFile = len(content.BulkColumn) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'file.csv', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS content
IF @lengthOfFile > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @lengthOfFile -- here you implement your bulk load 
END
```

Comment: len function is not returning number of rows, my file has 6000 rows and it is returning value of 138699, also I am using SIGLE_CLOB not SINGLE_NCLOB

Comment: It returns the number of chars in the whole csv file - the character length of it. If you know the character length of your headers, you could check `IF @lengthOfFile` is bigger than that, then it means there are more rows than just the header. In my case, the header is only 35 chars long, so I check `if @lengthOfFile > 35` and then do the import.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a solution. I am bulk inserting data and using `FIRSTROW = 2`.

If the CSV only contains the header row and no data, BULK INSERT fails with the error:

```
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2.
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Unfortunately error 7301 is used for various conditions and not just for empty CSV data.

So when it occurs I use this query to determine the number of rows in the CSV:

```sql
select len(BulkColumn) - len(replace(BulkColumn, char(10), '')) + 1 as line_count 
from openrowset(
   BULK 'path/to/my_csv.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'my_data_source',
   SINGLE_CLOB
) as data_file;
```

The `SINGLE_CLOB` parameter causes openrowset to load the entire CSV file into the `BulkColumn` column. Then we get the length of the string, then replace \n with '' and get the link of the resulting string. The difference between the two is the number of '\n' characters in the CSV.

The query adds 1 to it, in order to account for the total number of rows.

So when I encounter error 7031, I use this to check the number of rows of the CSV and if it is 2, then I allow the process to proceed without erroring out.

The performance of this is quite ok. Files that indeed only have a header row take less than a second to cound. I also tried it with a 430mb CSV file that had over 11mn rows and the query executed in around 6min.

Since I only cared about determining whether the CSV had data, I was able to cut the processing of the 430mb file down further to just 20s by only counting the new lines in the first 5,000 characters:

```
select len(substring(BulkColumn, 1, 5000)) - len(replace(substring(BulkColumn, 1, 5000), char(10), '')) + 1 as row_count
from openrowset(
   BULK 'import/manual_import/mp_is_other_tag_applications_2011-2020-06-06.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'ds_wasb',
   SINGLE_CLOB
) as data_file;
```

Comment: That is _so damn clever!_ And it indeed works very fast. Just verified by counting the 346K rows in a 93 MB file. It took 3 seconds.